# Is there a way to analyze packet intervals in order to output # of packets per second?

Tags: bash, traffic

I have about 54,000 packets to analyze and I am trying to determine the average # of packets per second (as well as the min and max # of packets during a given second)

My input file is a single column of the packet times (see sample below):

```
0.004

0.015

0.030

0.050

..

..

1999.99
```

I've used awk to determine the timing deltas but can't figure out a way to parse out the chunks of time to get an output of:

```
0-1s = 10 packets

1-2s = 15 packets
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can use awk to get the desired output.
Suppose your original input file is sample.txt, first thing to do is reverse sort it (sort -nr) then you can supply awk with the newly sorted file along with the time variable through awk "-v" argument. Perform your tests inside awk, make use of "next" to skip lines and "exit" to quit the awk script when needed.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    #
    for i in 0 1 2 3
    do
        sort -nr sample.txt |awk -v time=$i 'BEGIN{number=0}''{
                                if($1>=(time+1)){next}
                                else if( $1>=time && $1 <(time+1))
                                        {number+=1}
                                else{
                                printf "[ %d - %d [ : %d records\n",time,time+1,number;exit}
                        }'
    done
```

Here's the sample file:

```
0.1
0.2
0.8
.
.
0.94
.
.
1.5
1.9
.
3.0
3.6
```

Here's the program's output:

```
[ 1 - 2 [ : 5 records 
[ 2 - 3 [ : 8 records 
[ 3 - 4 [ : 2 records
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Is there a way to modify it so that it runs through a variable number of iterations?
Something like "for i in <# of lines in sample file>

Comment: Hi Mark !
You should note that the for loop should go untill you reach the max time value, and not the # of lines.
If you reverse sorted the sample file as i suggested in my answer, the max time value should be at the top of the file, you can get it by:

        max_time_integer=$( cat sample.txt  |sort -nr| head -1| awk '{print int($1)+1}')

After this loop over time from 0 to $max_time_integer using while or for loop:
    for i in `seq 0 $max_time_integer`
    do
    .
     done

Comment: Ah. Thanks so much for explaining.  I'm still very new to bash.

Comment: @MarkP Let me note that the approach above may be suitable to count #packets in the
specified (limited) range of period, it will not be efficient in execution time due to the *grep in the loop* if you wish to analyze the result in the whole period. Assuming your input file has 54,000 lines in 2,000 seconds of observation,
it iterates 2,000 times to grep over 54,000 lines. It may be worth trying for your future reference only :)

Comment: @tshiono That's right, your approach is way more efficient in execution time, especially since the file is already sorted.

Comment: @ussof Thanks for your comment, but my script works regardless of the order of the records.

Comment: Yup, my bad ! I've had another glance at your code, the array index you've set is actually the integer part of the line.(y)

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the followings:

With `bash`:

```
max=0
while read -r line; do
    i=${line%.*}                    # extract the integer part
    a[$i]=$(( ${a[$i]} + 1 ))       # increment the array element
    (( i > max )) && max=$i         # update the maximum index
done < sample.txt

# report the summary
for (( i=0; i<=max; i++ )); do
    printf "%d-%ds = %d packets\n" "$i" $(( i+1 )) "${a[$i]}"
done
```

With `AWK`:

```
awk '
    {
        i = int($0)
        a[i]++
        if (i > max) max = i
    }
    END {
        for (i=0; i<=max; i++)
            printf("%d-%ds = %d packets\n", i, i+1, a[i])
    }' sample.txt
```

sample.txt:

```
0.185
0.274
0.802
1.204
1.375
1.636
1.700
1.774
1.963
2.044
2.112
2.236
2.273
2.642
2.882
3.000
3.141
5.023
5.082
```

Output:

```
0-1s = 3 packets
1-2s = 6 packets
2-3s = 6 packets
3-4s = 2 packets
4-5s = 0 packets
5-6s = 2 packets
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The only issue I'm getting is that the # of instances for 0-1s is 123, but then the script outputs 123 for every interval after that... ie 1-2s = 123, 2-3s = 123, etc (which is not accurate).

I used your script below:
 #!/bin/bash
max=0
while read -r line
do
  i=${line%.*}
  a[$i]=$(( ${a[$i]} + 1 ))
  (( i > max )) && max=$i
done < packet-intervals-normalized.txt

#report summary
for (( i=0; i<=max; i++))
do
  printf "%d-%ds = %d packets\n" "$i" $(( i+1 )) "${a[$1]}"
done

Comment: @MarkP Your referring code differs from my answer. Please take a look of `"${a[$1]}"` at the almost end, which is written as `"${a[$i]}"` in my answer. That's why the same number repeats. How did you copy and paste my code?

Comment: ahhh yes. My apologies.  I'm just blind.  There was an issue with my copy and paste from host to VM so I had to hand-jam it.  Thanks for the assistance!